# Preventing ListView from Scrolling/Selecting Items when Pressing Keys

Tags: windows, winforms, listview, c++-cli, overriding

I tried to prevent my `ListView` from automatically scrolling down/selecting Item with the first letter I pressed.

So I tried to override it but this just doesn't work me.

```
public ref class ExtendedListView : public System::Windows::Forms::ListView
{
public:
    ExtendedListView();

    virtual void KeyPress(KeyEventArgs e) override
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys::W || e.KeyCode == Keys::A || e.KeyCode == Keys::S || e.KeyCode == Keys::D)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Test");
            return;
        }           
    }

};
```

(I added the `MessageBox` to test if it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'KeyPress' event fires before the change in listview (I tired it with list box)
The trick is to define 2 variables:

```
int selectedindex=0;
bool goBack=false;

private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode==Keys.B)
    {
        selectedindex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        goBack = true;
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (goBack)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedindex;
        goBack = false;
    }
}
```

This sample prevents the 'B' key for example.
I hope that is what u mean.

Comment: This is no good idea. It corrects what already was done. Better is to prevent it. So just use SelectedIndexChanging event. With this event you can prevent the selection change.

Comment: There is no such event for listview or listbox my friend

Comment: And what kind of event is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanging(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: look at the namespace that contains this! it is for System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: You are right. Strange that the .NET implementation for the list view doesn't support what the windows API offers: LVN_ITEMCHAMGING. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb774847(v=vs.85).aspx I was wrong that I was sure that this notification is available in :NET forms too.

Comment: Yes but the answer u provided down here worked better than mine. the SuppressKeyPress solution I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `SuppressKeyPress` from the [KeyEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

This should cause that the control ignores this key.